# How to prevent the mobile application closing and re-opening each time a test case is running?

Tags: python, automation, appium, python-unittest

I am performing mobile application automation using Appium with Python. I am also in need of creating HTML reports. I am wanting to create multiple test suites too. And all these works, except for one problem.

My problem is that the application closes and re-opens in every test case. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

(Please note that this is a sample code I'm putting on here.)

```
from adb.client import Client as AdbClient
import HtmlTestRunner
import datetime
import os, sys
import glob
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction

PLATFORM_VERSION = '8.1.0'



class Q_suite1_01(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.1.0'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Samsung Galaxy J7 Max'

    devices = AdbClient(host= "127.0.0.1", port= 5037).devices()
    for device in devices:
        desired_caps['udid'] = device.serial

    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.testapp'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.testapp.MainActivity'
    url = "http://localhost:{}/wd/hub".format(4723)
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_caps)




def install(self):
    print 'ABDC!'


def run_app(self):
    try:
        x = self.driver.is_app_installed('com.quallogi')
        if x is True:
            print 'App is already installed.'
        else:
            print 'App is not installed.'
    except:
        print 'App not installed'


def signin(self):
    sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@text,"Login") and contains(@class, "android.widget.TextView")]').click()
    print 'Sign'


def testcase_Install_app(self):
    self.install()

def testcase_Run_app(self):
    self.run_app()

def testcase_SignIn(self):
    self.signin()


# def testcase_Install_app(self):
#     self.install()
#     self.run_app()
#     self.signin()
#



def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()



if __name__ == '__main__':

     result = []

     suite1= unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Q_suite1_01)
     result.append(HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='./HTML Reports/' 
     + str(datetime.date.today())).run(suite1))
     print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

At the first I want to recomend you to look at the Appium capability "noReset" -    "Don't reset app state before this session." (true, false).

If i right understand you question. What do you meant "application closes and re-opens in every test case"? Can you describe it more detail?

Comment: What I meant was that this script runs successfully, but it happens like this. It opens the specific app runs the 1st test case, gives the print statement as "ABDC!" , then closes the app. Again runs the app and runs the 2nd test case, gives the print statement as "App is already installed.", closes the app. And again opens the app, performs the button click and gives the print statement "Sign" and cloes the app again.

Comment: probably, that behave can happened, because function "setup" runs several times, but its not obvoiously from your code.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this and stop reopening the app with each test case?

Comment: Its not so perfect solution, but you need to move "non-repeat" code(all code at that case) from section "setUp" to next first section (like "install") and try to start.

May be better solution will be create whole "self-sufficient" sections of test. I meant, include all code and be able possibility to restart application after each test. For more information look please https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html from that sentanse "The setUp() and tearDown() methods allow you to define instructions that will be executed before and after each test method. They are cover...."

Comment: Thanks. I got this fixed by using setUpClass and tearDownClass.